# NSString to Double Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Probably really simple but I don't understand...
I have an NSString `50.81114` and I want to convert it into a double...
Currently I am using `[string doubleValue]` but this is coming out as `50.811140000002`
What's going on?!

**Disco**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double` (and any floating point number) has its own limit of accuracy, normally it would be around 15-16 digits. Note this is not just for Objective-C, but for all the languages because of the limit of binary floating point presentation.

What you show is just normal, since `50.81114` cannot be accurately presented in binary, approximation must be used.

You can read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) for further reading.

Answer (score 11):

due to limited precision `double` can't store `50.81114`. The closest value that can be stored in a double is `50.811140000002`.

Use [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead. Like this:

```
NSString *string = @"50.81114";
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain this number as a decimal, rather than binary, number then use `NSDecimalNumber` rather than `double`.